# Using Highlighted Content to retrieve all docs with a managed property value

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

I want to configure the highlighted content web part on a hub site to bring back all documents that have a managed property column set a certain value.

I can configure a filter or CAML if I point to single library but what if I need to incorporate all document libraries in the hub site family

Here, I set up my managed property

[image]

next I configure my HCWP

[image]

Nest I weep as nothing is retrieved :-( .  I wonder if this restriction in HCWPs .. Is there a way of seeing the final query?

Answer (score 0):

In the quert text(KQL), there seems to be a problem with the symbol "=". Try to use ":" instead of "=". Check if it works.

For example:

```
contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that